# Emacs style highlighting for inc-search in vim

Tags: search, vim, highlight

I realize that this question has been posed before on this forum, but I didn't find an answer so here goes..

In Vim, is there a way to enable on-the-fly highlighting for all matches when searching?

If I enable incsearch and type "/something" it will highlight the first match only. If I enable hlsearch and type "/something", nothing happens until I press enter (it only highlights the previous search).

In emacs the first match will be highlighted, and (after a slight delay) all other matches on the screen are highlighted in a different color, giving almost instant feedback when scanning for matches in a piece of code.

Answer (score 3):

use the n-search feature of easy-motion , it does exactly what you need(look in the gif demo)
BONUS: it also dims down the background for you that really makes searching easy

https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion#n-character-search-motion

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the [incsearch.vim](https://github.com/haya14busa/incsearch.vim) plugin:

[image: Emacs-like incsearch: move the cursor while incremental searching]

*You need to first [install](https://github.com/haya14busa/incsearch.vim#installation) the plugin and [bind `<Over>(incsearch-...)`](https://github.com/haya14busa/incsearch.vim#emacs-like-incsearch-move-the-cursor-while-incremental-searching).*

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for :set incsearch together with hlsearch. However all hits will have the same color.

Comment: This plugin adds highlighting to the match under the cursor: https://github.com/dahu/vim-mash

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but like I pointed out in my question this combo does not give the results I am looking for. hlsearch will only highlight all matches after enter has been pressed, even if I use incsearch. What I wanted was for the matches to be highlighted as I type, before pressing enter.

Comment: Thank you for the link El Isra, I will check it out.

Comment: The plugin was not really a solution either, unfortunately. It highlights the match under the cursor when using n,N,* etc

Comment: for me vim together with hlsearch and incsearch start highlighting as  soon as I start typing. No plugin needed (Fedora 16).

Comment: on OSX (Snow Leopard), even with incsearch, hlsearch only highlights after enter has been pressed.

Comment: @pgampe With `incsearch` and `hlsearch` the next match will be highlighted as the search is typed, and all matches are highlighted after enter is pressed.